# .net framework dev pack 4.6.2 doesn't seem to work in VS Pro 2022

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I have this project that for reasons that are not of interest right now, must stay in v4.6 of .Net framework.

I just installed VS Pro 2022, and when I open the solution it tells me that I must:

A. Upgrade to v4.8.
B. Download the 4.6 pack.
C. Unload the project.

I already downloaded and installed the 4.6 pack, and yet, VS Studio continues to present the same options over and over.

Anything I can do about this?